# export html file from java with tree structure information

Tags: java, html, swt, jface

I am having a tree structure information in my SWT application, That i want to export in HTML file in same as it is means collapsible and expandable.

I had look in to this that i need to write some `javascript(html)` that should read by browser and information should be in tree structure way. Need to maintain action for expand and collapse event too.
Like following:

```
+Category1
-Category2
    +Sub-Cat1
    +Sub-Cat2
    +Sub-Cat3
    +Sub-Cat4
+Category3
+Category4
```

Please suggest me a feasible approach.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a Java question. It seems like it's only about HTML ("How do I make a collapsible/expandable tree in HTML?")

Comment: @immibis but I need to write that html file by java programming.

Comment: the Java part of this question is "how do I write to a file?"